# LabVIEW Complicated If Statements

Tags: if-statement, labview, dmx512

Background: I am trying to configure a DMX turntable in LabVIEW, it has two settings for rotating: coarse (360 degrees in 255 points) and fine (1 degree in 255 points). I need to be able to firstly execute a command to move to the closest available DMX position in coarse mode, then make up the difference in fine mode.

e.g. I want to turn to 90 degrees, this is equivalent to a DMX value of 63.75 however this is rounded down to 63. The real value in degrees is now 88.94 so I need to make up the extra 1.06 degrees by using the fine setting (I can only make up 1 degree but 89.94 is close enough to 90).

I can execute the coarse setting just fine however I need some kind of "if" statement to say "if real degree value is less than input value, make up the difference". Case Structures do not provide enough control to use this complicated "if" statement, what can I use instead?

Answer (score 4):

255 coarse steps * 255 fine steps per coarse step = 65025 possible steps.

360 degrees / 65025 = ~ 0.00536 degrees per step.

Divide your desired angle by this constant, then use this as the X input to [quotient and remainder](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361H-01/glang/quotient_and_remainder/). Y would be 255. The Quotient will represent the coarse value to adjust and the Remainder represents the fine value.

63 coarse steps and 191 fine steps.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any condition. Use the Quotient and Remainder function with 255/4 to get 63 and .75. Do the 63 coarse movement, then take the .75 and multiply it by 360. This will tell you many fine steps you need to take (270, which is 255 + 15. You can use Q&R again to know how many whole turns to make and how much you have left in the last turn).